# OpenStack monasca empty results

Tags: openstack

Recently i've installed `Monasca` for monitoring my multi-domain `openstack` lab cloud.

But it shows everything empty:

```
$  monasca dimension-name-list --tenant-id=$(openstack project show service -c id -f value)

$ monasca dimension-name-list --tenant-id=$(openstack project show iProject -c id -f value)

$ monasca metric-list \
--tenant-id $(openstack project show service -c id -f value) \
--dimensions project_id=$(openstack project show iProject -c id -f value)
```

All with empty results.

Also i've configured `cloudkitty` to use `monasca` as collector but it also collects noting.

I can't find any tutorial on the web except general talks and seminars!
can anybody help?

Answer (score -1):

You need to source your OpenStack RC file:

[image: Screenshot]

1. Download it from your OpenStack window's top right (see above photo), doesn't have to be the admin account.
2. Copy to wherever your Monasca client is installed
3. Type this CLI, and input your password:

   ```
   source <your-openstack-rc-file>
   ```
4. Now you can run the above commands.

Comment: If there is no auth, ```cli``` shows the proper unauthorized message. Monasca needs to get metrics from ceilometer and have to configure ceilometer publisher section to push ```nova``` instances data to monasca. I'd seen empty results because there was no data.